# Search for entire word only when using string.includes() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to search whether a string is present inside an array of strings using the string.includes() method as shown below

```js
var theString = "clovers are the best";
var theArray = ["lovers", "loved", "clove", "love", "clovers"];
for (i = 0; i < theArray.length; i += 1) {
  if (theString.includes(theArray[i])) {
    console.log(theArray[i]);
  }
}
```

The output I get includes "lovers", "clove" and "love" in addition to the expected "clovers." How can I force the search to look for entire string only?

Comment: Use `===` instead of `String.prototype.includes`

Comment: Did you mean to write `theArray[i].includes(theString)`?

Comment: I think you want `theArray.includes(theString)` with no loop.

Comment: Ah, but in my actual code, "theString" is actually a sentence. For example theString = "clovers are the best"

Comment: Well how about you [edit] your question to give a complete example? Anyway, you can do what you want using a regular expression match instead of `.includes()`.

Comment: You'd have to use or build a regular expression. `/\blove\b/` matches love but not clove. It matches love-making though.

Answer (score 2):

You're testing each element of the array to see if the element is present in the string.  You can just test the array to see if a particular string is a member, which is closer to your description of the problem.

```js
    var theString = "clovers";
    var theArray = ["lovers", "loved", "clove", "love", "clovers"];
    var idx = theArray.findIndex( e => e === theString );
    console.log(idx);
    // finding a string done two ways
    idx = theArray.indexOf( theString );
    console.log(idx);
```

If idx is not -1, the string is present in the array

Comment: Is this different somehow from `indexOf`?

Comment: @torazaburo They do simliar things.  indexOf takes a search term as an argument.  findIndex takes a function.  indexOf may be more appropriate in this instance since the function is a direct comparison

Comment: @Tibrogargan you should add this to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's returning the extras because they are a part of "clovers". My recommendation would be to split the string individual words:

```js
var input = prompt("enter string").split(" ");
unallowed=",.()[]{}-_=+!@#$%^&*~`|\\<>?/\"':;"; //list of not allowed chars
for(i=0; i<input.length; i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<unallowed.length;j++)
    {
        input[i]=input[i].split(unallowed[j]);
        if(typeof(input[i])=="object")
            input[i]=input[i].join("");
    }
    
}
var theArray = ["lovers", "loved", "clove", "love", "clovers"];
for (i = 0; i < theArray.length; i += 1) {
  for(j=0; j<input.length; j++)
      if (input[j].toLowerCase()==theArray[i]) {
        console.log(theArray[i]);
  }
}
```

edit: fixed a few derps in my code.

Comment: What if the real sentence to be tested isn't hardcoded, and might contain punctuation? E.g., `"I don't like clovers, but I like oak trees and tulips."`

Comment: punctuation complicates it a bit, it just needs to be removed.